# SQL Server 2014 Index Optimization: Any benefit with including primary key in indexes?

Tags: sql-server, performance

After running a query, the SQL Server 2014 Actual Query Plan shows a missing index like below:

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_1 ON Table1 (Column1) INCLUDE
 (PK_Column,SomeOtherColumn)
```

The missing index suggests to include the Primary Key column in the index. The table is clustered index with the PK_Column.

I am confused and it seems that I don’t get the concept of Clustered Index Primary Key right.

My assumption was: when a table has a clustered PK, all of the non-clustered indexes point to the PK value. Am I correct? If I am, why the query plan missing index asks me to include the PK column in the index?

Comment: I think the suggestion is redundant (in general, the missing index suggestions require close scrutiny to see which ones are really a good idea, because the optimizer will suggest everything and the kitchen sink). You could try creating the index with just `INCLUDE (SomeOtherColumn)` and see if the query uses it and the hint disappears, which would be a pretty solid confirmation.

Comment: Can you show the query plan and schema of tables involved

Comment: Your understanding is correct - the *leaf level* of any nonclustered index contains the columns of that index itself, any *included* columns, **and** the clustering key column(s). The problem is really the tuning advisor : it's a piece of software that's known to suggest rather unnecessary, something utterly superfluous changes. Don't just blindly use those recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**
Index advised is not valid,but it doesn't make any difference.See below tests section for details..

After researching for some time,found an [answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/is-it-ok-to-blindly-add-missing-indexes) and  below statement  explains convincingly about missing index feature..

> they only look at a single query, or a single operation within a single query. They don't take into account what already exists or your other query patterns.
>
> You still need a thinking human being to analyze the overall indexing strategy and make sure that you index structure is efficient and cohesive.

So coming to your question,this index advised may be valid ,but should not to be taken for granted. The index advised is useful for SQL Server for the **particular query** executed, to reduce cost.

This is the index that was advised..

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_1 ON Table1 (Column1) 
        INCLUDE (PK_Column, SomeOtherColumn)
```

Assume you have a query like below..

```
select pk_column, someothercolumn 
from table 
where column1 = 'somevalue'
```

SQL Server tries to scan a narrow index as well if available, so in this case an index as advised will be helpful..

Further you didn't share the schema of table, if you have an index like below

```
create index nci_test on table(column1)
```

and a query of below form will advise again same index as stated in question

```
select pk_column, someothercolumn 
from table 
where column1 = 'somevalue'
```

**Update :**
i have orders table with below schema..

```
[orderid] [int] NOT NULL Primary key,
[custid] [char](11) NOT NULL,
[empid] [int] NOT NULL,
[shipperid] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[orderdate] [date] NOT NULL,
[filler] [char](160) NOT NULL
```

Now i created one more index of below structure..

```
create index onlyempid on orderstest(empid)
```

Now when i have a query of below form

```
select empid,orderid,orderdate --6.3 units
from orderstest 
where empid=5
```

index advisor will advise below missing index .

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX empidalongwithorderiddate
ON [dbo].[orderstest] ([empid])
INCLUDE ([orderid],[orderdate])--you can drop orderid too ,it doesnt make any difference
```

If you can see orderid is also included in above suggestion

now lets create it and observe both structures..

---Root level-------

For index onlyempid..
[image]

for index  empidalongwithorderiddate
[image]

----leaf level-------

For index onlyempid..
[image]

for index  empidalongwithorderiddate
[image]

As you can see , creating as per suggestion makes no difference,Even though it is invalid.

I Assume suggestion was made by Index advisor based on query ran and is **specifically for the query** and it has  no idea of other indexes involved

Comment: The schema is aligned with what you have in the query. Are you suggesting that the IX_1 is actually valid for the query you have? Based on the other comment I think PK_Column should not be included and imposes storage overhead without any benefit. Are you agree with that?

Comment: yes for the query types i have in my answer,index suggested are valid ,but only for this query

Comment: ok, now I understand your answer. how your 1st query benefits from including PK_Column? The index already has the PK data, why do we need to include it again?

Comment: the index advised was using column1 as key column and optimizer will choose a plan that benfits from scanning narrow index rather than whole clustered index

Comment: Yes, but how INCLUDE (PK_Column) help? PK_Column is already included in any non-clustered index, or did I get the concept wrong?

Comment: How did you query the index contents? Would you be able to share the query that shows the index nodes? Thanks so much for help.

Comment: sure ,i can provide them in some time when i reach home

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your schema, nor your queries. Just guessing.

Please correct me if this theory is incorrect.

You are right that non-clustered indexes point to the PK value. Imagine you have large database (for example gigabytes of files) stored on ordinary platter hard-drive. Lets suppose that the disk is fragmented and the PK_index is saved physical far from your Table1 Index.

Imagine that your query need to evaluate Column1 and PK_column as well. The query execution read Column1 value, then PK_value, then Column1 value, then PK_value...

The hard-drive platter is spinning from one physical place to another, this can take time.

Having all you need in one index is more effective, because it means reading one file sequentially.